# Relationship with derivative

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $F :[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that it’s derivative $F’(x)$ is increasing in $x$. Then which of the following is true for every $x$,$y$ in $[0,1]$ with $x>y$.

1. $F(x)-F(y) = (x-y)F’(x)$
2. $F(x)-F(y) \geq (x-y)F’(x)$
3. $F(x)-F(y) \leq (x-y)F’(x)$

4.$F(x) -F(y) = F’(x) -F’(y)$

If I take the function to be $F(x) = x^2$ and take $x = 1$ and $y= 0$ then $(x-y)F’(x) = (1-0)F’(1) = 2$ which is greater than $F(1)-F(0) = 1$ , so I’m thinking that the correct option should be 3, but I am not sure about my approach, I feel like a formal proof would require using limits, but I couldn’t figure out how exactly to go about it, can someone provide a way to formally prove it please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to Kavi Rama Murthy.

MVT:

For $x>y:$

$F(x)-F(y)= (x-y)F'(a)$ , $a \in (y,x)$.

Since $F' $ is increasing: $F'(y)\le F'(a) \le F'(x).$

Hence 1)-3)?

4) $f(t)=t^2$;

$f(x)-f(y)=x^2-y^2= (x-y)(x+y)$.

$=f'(x)-f'(y)=2(x-y)$.

Now choose $x,y \in (0,1)$(Why?) to rule out 4).

Appended:

Proof of option 3:

We have  MVT:

$F(x)-F(y)=  F'(a)(x-y) \le$

$F'(x)(x-y)$,

since $F'(a)\le F'(x)$, recall $y <a<x$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was actually looking for a formal proof, like if I wasn’t given the options and the question was to proove 3. then how would you go about it.

Comment: user601297.Does this appended part answer your question?

Comment: The first line is throwing me off, $F(x)-F(y) =$ what?? There is nothing after the equal sign

Comment: Ok after thinking about it for a while, I got the proof, thanks

Answer (score 2):

3) is true (by MVT and the fact that $f'$ is increasing) and all others are false. Consider the function $f(t)=t^{2}$ to see that other options are all false.

Comment: Can you tell me the process to come to that conclusion?